# strange behavior expect script under cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, expect

i have simple expect script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

#TFTP

exp_internal 1
log_file expect.stdout.log

set timeout 60
set hostname [lindex $argv 0];
set login [lindex $argv 1];
set password [lindex $argv 2];
set iptftp [lindex $argv 3];
set file [lindex $argv 4];

match_max 1000000
spawn telnet $hostname

sleep 1
expect "login:" {send "$login\n"}
sleep 1
expect "Password:" {send "$password\n"}
sleep 3
expect "*#" {send -- "upload cfg_toTFTP $iptftp $file config_id 1\n"}
sleep 3

expect "*#" {send -- "logout\n"}
```

this script run via php script which connect to mysql DB and get hostname, login etc and . If I run script via shell /usr/bin/php /home/swbackup/backup.php - all OK. Under cron, after script login to switch send only first letter from command upload cfg_toTFTP **u** and nothing more

```
expect: does " \r\n\r\n\rDGS-1100-06/ME:5# " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " \r\n\r\n\rDGS-1100-06/ME:5#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\n\r\n\rDGS-1100-06/ME:5#"
send: sending "upload cfg_toTFTP 10.0.4.240 174610_backup.cfg config_id 1\n" to { exp7 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*#"? no
u
expect: does " u" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "*#"? no
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried different options, but nothing helps

Comment: The problem still exists. I tried different options, like set term, timeout, other commands - script expect only first symbol. Problem with D-Link

Comment: WTF. On the one switch i upgrade firmware to last version, problem is away. How firmware affect to process upload cfg via cron :(